# App keeps crashing before even opening in Android Studio (Java)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-activity

First of all, I'm an absolute beginner when it comes to Java and Android Studio. I am creating a simple app and am trying to implement activity switching with animations. However, something seems to be causing the app to crash before it even opens on my phone or any virtual device. I am (pretty) sure the onClick() is not causing it.

```
/*home.java*/
package com.example.memorygame;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

public class home extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageButton ibNext;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.home);

        ibNext=(ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ibNext);
        ibNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
               startActivity(new Intent(home.this, start.class));
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_left_in,R.anim.slide_right_out);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

```
/*start.java*/
package com.example.memorygame;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

public class start extends AppCompatActivity {



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.start);
    }
}
```

Comment: Use Logcat [to examine the stack trace associated with your crash](https://commonsware.com/Jetpack/pages/chap-debug-001.html). If you do not understand the stack trace, edit your question and post the stack trace here.

Comment: @CommonsWare it seems there was an issue refactoring when I renamed my MainActivity.java to home.java but I can't find the location of the outdated name. Here is the error. https://pastebin.com/1HyJRyBz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you did a refactoring of the name of your main activity, it's most probably because you did not change the name in your manifest.

Check [this link](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro#example) about how you register an activity in your manifest file.

Don't forget to declare action `android.intent.action.MAIN` and category `android.intent.category.LAUNCHER` for your main activity (the one shown after launching the app), as shown in the example at the bottom of the page.

If this is not causing your problem search for the old name in the entire application (CTRL+SHIFT+F).

Comment: Thank you! This fixed the issue. I also forgot to add my other activity to the manifest.